# How can I set the routes correctly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Here is a sample code:

```
    var x = require('./folder/usefile');

    var Auth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

    module.exports = function(app){
    console.log('inside function(app)'); //line 1 executed!

    var player = express.Router();
    var finalRun = express.Router();

    app.use('/api/usefile',player);

    player.get('/', Auth, x.login);

    player.post('/post', Auth, function(req, res){
      x.register});

    app.use('/api',finalRun);
console.log('inside api'); //line 2 is executed!
    }
```

In `usefile` my login function is present which is exported.

I am using passport here, whose functionality is present in separate file here it is used only for authentication.

When I ran http://localhost:8080/api/usefile/---> for `get` method, it is displaying 404. same for `post` method.

The console is printing line 1 and line 2(have mentioned in the comments) and the flow is line1, line2.

Can anyone help me to find what mistake I have made here?

Comment: @robertklep...need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created two Router instances `player` and `finalRun`.  There are two main issues:

1. This line `player.use('/usefile',player)` should be `app.use('/usefile',player)`.  `express.Router().use` is used to add a middleware for all routes registered to the router (in this case `player`). For example, if you wanted to use the `Auth` middleware from Passport for every `player` route, you could declare it as `player.use(Auth)`.
2. You are not declaring any route handling for the `finalRun` router. So in this case, your route handlers registered with `player` will handle `host/usefile` and `finalRun` will handle any `host/api`.

If you are wanting the handlers registered with `player` to handle `/api/usefile`, using a single router instance would be far simpler.

Register the `/api/usefile` path with the `player` router like:

```
app.use('/api/usefile', player);
```

[Docs for `app.use`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)

[Docs for `router.use`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use)

Comment: Actually, I have set `app.use('/api', finalRun);` to set all the routes that I have created on a single endpoint.

Comment: @AdityaJain `finalRun` is a router that doesn't have any route handlers (you add a router handler with this: `finalRun.get(...); finalRun.post(...)`, like what you're doing with the `player` router).

Comment: Although I have edited in my code `app.use('/api/usefile');` The code is getting inside my `player.get('/', Auth, function(req, res){
    console.log('inside get route');` code and displaying the console, but it is not getting the x.ogin function which is in another file exported. @metame

Comment: @AdityaJain you're also not doing anything with those `x` functions. If you want to call them, use `x.login(req, res)` (or this: `player.get('/', Auth, x.login)`).

Comment: @robertklep `finalRun` is used to set all the routers that are used with a single endpoint.

Comment: @AdityaJain I don't know what that means. In the code you're using, `finalRun` isn't used for anything.

Comment: @robertklep I have moved a bit closer to my code now, the routes are getting called now.. :-) you are GOD :D

Comment: @robertklep How will I check for the `post` as `get` and post have the same endpoints.Although I can use different for `post` but if they have same then ?As I have changed and check it shows 404 error.

Comment: @robertklep I have edited my question and done the changes, so till now my `get` route is called 200ok when I put `player.get(' / ', x.login);` but when I use `player.get(' / ',Auth, x.login;)` I get an error on `unauthorized` with 401 status code. And please tell me the `player.post(' / ' , Auth, function(req, res){ x.register});` where am I wrong in this?

Comment: @AdityaJain the 401 means "unauthorized", so there's something wrong with the login procedure. And you might solve the issue with `x.register` in _exactly_ the same way as you did with `x.login`.

Comment: @robertklep  I did same as with `x.login` but it shows that post method needs a callback so I place `function(req, res)` and ok with the 401 error I will check it out, but what about `post`?

Comment: @AdityaJain if you have specific question, you should open a new question on SO :)

Comment: @robertklep I will do so and let you know the link...thank you Robert for helping and sharing so much knowledge :)

Comment: @robertklep please see this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971117/how-to-use-the-routes-correctly-using-express-router